# rosdep install joy error

Tags: ros, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get this error when trying to install joy.
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource joy
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/usr/share/ftcsim-0.1/ros
ROS path [2]=/usr/share/ftcsim-0.1/ros
ROS path [3]=/usr/share/ftcsim-0.1/ros
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/hydro/share
ROS path [5]=/opt/ros/hydro/stacks
Can anyone help me out?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/142006/rosdep-install-joy-error/) by [damaximum](https://answers.ros.org/users/13556/damaximum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem, I used sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-joy and it worked.

---

Originally posted by [pablospawlos](https://answers.ros.org/users/13716/pablospawlos/) with karma: 36 on 2014-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2